# Adjustando un texto

Tags: javascript

necesito una ayuda con este ejercicio. Debo crear una funcion que recibe dos argumentos: un string y un número, que determina la longitud a la que se debe ajustar el string. Si la longitud del string es mayor al valor del segundo parámetro, se debe cortar. De lo contrario, se debe completar con espacios.

La función debe retornar el string ajustado.

```
function adjustText(str, num) {
      if (str.length > num) {
        let cut = str.slice(0, num)
        return cut;
      } else {}
 }
```

La primera parte que corta el string funciona, pero estoy bloqueado de como agregar espacios vacios a un string, he intentado convertir el string en un array y recorrerlo para cuando str.length < num haga push y añada un espacio, pero falló en la implementación

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que la mejor opción es usar métodos específicos de cadenas, en este caso, [padEnd()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) que llena con el caracter especificado hasta obtener la longitud deseada.

Por cierto, no es necesario crear una nueva variable, se puede trabajar con la misma que se recibe por parámetro.

```js
function adjustText(str, num) {
    if (str.length > num) {
        // Cortar
        str = str.slice(0, num)
    } else {
        // Llenar con espacios
        str = str.padEnd(num, ' ');
    }
    return str;
}

// Mostrar con delimitadores para comprobar
console.log(`[${adjustText('Solo doce caracteres', 12)}]`);
console.log(`[${adjustText('Llenar', 12)}]`);
```

De hecho, `.padEnd()` llena con espacios solo cuando es necesario, garantizando la longitud deseada, y se puede combinar con `.slice()` en una sola línea, simplificando el código:

```js
function adjustText(str, num) {
    return str.padEnd(num, ' ').slice(0, num);
}

// Mostrar con delimitadores para comprobar
console.log(`[${adjustText('Solo doce caracteres', 12)}]`);
console.log(`[${adjustText('Llenar', 12)}]`);
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear un contador de esta manera:

```javascript
function adjustText(str, num) {
      if (str.length > num) {
        let cut = str.slice(0, num)
        return cut;
      } else {
        for (var i=0; i <= (num - str.length); i++) {
          str=str + " ";
        }
        return str;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Se puede hacer un poco mejor pero basicamente es recorrer la diferencia y concatenar

```js
function adjustText(str, num) {

      if (str.length > num) 
      return str.slice(0, num)
        else {
      Array((num-str.length)).fill(1).map((t) => {
            str+=" ";
            });
      }
    return str
 }
 
 console.log(adjustText('hola',45))
```